# count rank of product listed in search results on website and get rank into excel using python

Tags: python

I am a new to Python.
I started web browser automatically using selenium package and opened e-commerce website(like Amazon) and searched my products in the search bar. 
This I did successfully. 
But now, on performing this search I want to get what's rank of my product in search result using Python. (Ex. Will it be 5th/ 6th/50th) in the search result and then store that rank in CSV. I brainstormed a lot but I can't come up with the code. Can anyone please help me?

Sample of Response:
 Consider my mobile product company name is Yu yu yureka
Open flipkart> type 'mobile' and Hit search button >
 You will see title, picture, description of motorola
 next of yu yu yureka. So here I want the rank of my products. If it has different products and comes at 6rd and 5th position I want to retrieve the product name and the rank as 6 and 5 both.

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\All\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/')

driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)


driver.find_element_by_class_name("LM6RPg").send_keys("mobile")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("vh79eN").click()
```

Now I want get the search result data sort rank of Yu Yu Yureka(both the products) in search result?
It is 5th or 6th there
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you showed a sample of the response. And assuming you just want the output to be a CSV string?

Comment: I have added it. Please take a look now. Hope it is clear. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds like you need to start by using a module like `selenium` to connect to the website and navigate the search steps you described. After that, ranking won't be very difficult. Please provide [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for additional help.

Comment: Hi, updated the code! I opened the browser and did the search successfully! Now only part left is retrieving that search result rank! I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick the elements from the list of elements of class name _2_KrJI and get their text attribute.

```
element_list =  driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_2_KrJI")
print(element_list[4].text)
print(element_list[5],text)
```

Comment: This will give me product ranking. I am interested in finding out... whether my product appears on 1st page or second page? if it's on the first page then it is appearing at 5th position or 7th position?Consider first page has 10 products listed,if its listed in second position on the second page, then it should give position as 10+2= 12.

Comment: Several browsers support the <F12> key to open a debug window. In debug, you can inspect the browser window to identify the elements you're interested in, and then use a similar strategy to what I used in Answer 1 to iterate through your list elements matching a class or children of an element, etc. Then look at their text attribute to see whether they contain the desired value.

Comment: Yeah. I did check that but there is no attribute such as data sort ranking. I think I need to count the divs between occurrences. But I am unable to understand how to do that. Is this the correct approach or can there be anything else that's easier?

Comment: You're on the right track. The list returned by selenium will be the order they appear on the page. So you should be able to iterate through the list, using an enumerator `for index,element in enumerate(driver.get_elements_by_class('whatever')):` where the index will contain 0, 1, 2, 3 (the index in the list), and the element will contain the object whose text can be retrieved using `element.text`. When element.text matches desired text, print/save the index.

Comment: Hi I tried doing that but it is giving me error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>[index=enumerate (driver.find_element_by_class_name('search-result-product-url'))']
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable